# Bootstrap accordion in mvc view not collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

i have a bootstrap collapse on a view, it being generated programmatically with a list, but in page every thing is open, upon clicking nothing collapses, here is code

```
<div id="accordion">
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card-@item.id">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne-@item.id">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@item.id" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="@item.id">
                        @item.name
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="@item.id" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne-@item.id" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
}
</div>
```

if i remove 'show' class, like in code below, everything is collapsed and won't open

```
<div id="@item.id" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne-@item.id" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
              </div>
          </div>
```

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

remove the show class from your div you want to be collapsed
in foreach, otherwise, each div is going to be open after iterating.

```
<div id="@item.id" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne- 
      @item.id" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
 </div>
```